# lapack zheev.f gives wrong eigenvalues

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, lapack

I wrote a f90 program to test the subroutine zheev.f provided by lapack.
What I do is building a 6x6 diagonal matrix (with real entries for testing purposes) and compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The eigenvectors I get are correct, but the eigenvalues are wrong, and at the moment I can't understand why. I would much appreciate any help.

Here is the code:

```
program main
implicit none
external ZHEEV
complex*16, parameter :: Re=(1.0,0.0)
complex*16 :: egvc(6,6)
complex*16 :: egvl(6)
complex*16 :: Dmat(6,6)
!Lapack variables
character(len=1) :: JOBZ,UPLO
integer :: N,LDA,LWORK,INFO
real*16, allocatable :: W(:), RWORK(:)
complex*16, allocatable :: A(:,:), WORK(:)
!Dummies
integer :: i

!Inizialize lapack variables
JOBZ="V"
UPLO="U"
INFO=0
N=6
LDA=6
LWORK=N*2-1
allocate(A(N,N),W(N),WORK(LWORK),RWORK(N*3-2))
A=0.0*Re
W=0.0
WORK=0.0*Re
RWORK=0.0

!Initialize the matrix
Dmat=0.0*Re
do i=1,6
 Dmat(i,i)=i*Re
enddo

!Query
A=Dmat
LWORK=-1
call zheev(JOBZ,UPLO,N,A,LDA,W,WORK,LWORK,RWORK,INFO)
if (INFO.eq.0) then
 LWORK=int(real(WORK(1)))
 deallocate(WORK)
 allocate(WORK(LWORK))
 WORK=0.0*Re
else if (INFO.ne.0) then
 write(*,*) "From zheev: query for optimal workspace failed: STOP!"
 deallocate(A,W,WORK,RWORK)
 stop
endif

!Diagonalization
A=Dmat
call zheev(JOBZ,UPLO,N,A,LDA,W,WORK,LWORK,RWORK,INFO)
!Check
if (INFO.ne.0) then
 write(*,*) "Diagonalization failed INFO=",INFO," STOP!"
 deallocate(A,W,WORK,RWORK)
 stop
endif
egvl=W
egvc=A

do i=1,6
 write(55,*) egvl(i)
enddo

do i=1,6
 write(66,*) real(egvc(i,:))
 write(77,*) aimag(egvc(i,:))
enddo

deallocate(A,W,WORK,RWORK)
stop
end program main
```

In the case above eigenvalues should be {1,2,3,4,5,6}. What I get is instead (approximately) {2,131072,33554432,0,0,0}. Similar strange results for other simple matrices including 6x6 identity matrix.

Here is how I compiled the code:

gfortran test_zheev.f90 -o test_zheev.x -llapack -lblas

Here is the output of 'lsb_release -a' command:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Here is how I installed the libraries:

sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev

(Following this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/623578/installing-blas-package)

Comment: Use tag fortran to get more attention. Use version tags as an addition when necessary to distinguish.

Comment: BTW `REAL*16` and `COMPLEX*16` are NOT compatible.

Comment: Changing real*16 to real*8 solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you learn about kind values - real*8 and complex*16 are not and have never been standard fortran, and since the kind mechanism within the language is also more powerful and flexible it would be better to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Ian.